# Why is this WPF custom DependencyProperty binding on value converter not executing?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, ivalueconverter

I am building what I have learned is basically an accordion control, with a selection mode that ensures that only one section is open at the time. Each section is implemented using Expander controls, so if on Expander is opened, all others should close.

I have done that in the following manner:

- Added a property representing the Id of the currently open section, *ActiveQuestionId* on the view model (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged)
- Created a converter inheriting from DependencyObject that is able to convert the *ActiveQuestionId* to a boolean indicating whether a specific section should be open, by adding a DependencyProperty *ControlValue* to the converter that indicates which section  that it belongs to
- Creating a local converter for each section with *ControlValue* bound to the *QuestionId* of its section

While the converter methods executes successfully, the problem is the DependencyProperty *ControlValue* is never set even though it binds successfully to a value and don't raise any errors. I have confirmed this through various debugging. So the result is that all sections are stuck with the default value, rendering the accordion selection behavior I want, useless.

Why is the DependencyProperty binding being ignored? Is it because it is defined within a binding, or something else?

**Remarks**

Everything is data-driven, and worked great in static a mockup I did before implementing the generic data-driven version. A fully data driven solution is a must, so using one way multi bindings or hardcoded XAML parameters (the solutions I have been able to find for related issues) is not an option.

It is important to note that all other bindings work perfect, so there is no problem DataContext wise. As everything should work (in my mind), this is also why I have not gone the WPF Toolkit Accordion way yet, so please do not suggest this initially (unless it is really the only way). First of, being new to WPF, I would like to understand why this is not working.

**XAML (extract - some names changed to obfuscate business meaning - central part is *IsExpanded* binding):**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionSection.QuestionAssignments}"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"           
          Style="{x:Null}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grey400Brush}" 
                BorderThickness="0 1 0 0">
            <Expander Background="{StaticResource Grey200Brush}" 
                      Foreground="Black" 
                      Padding="0" 
                      Margin="0">
                <Expander.IsExpanded>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:TypeOfParentControl}"
                             Path="DataContext.ActiveQuestionId"
                             Mode="TwoWay">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <converters:TestConverter ControlValue="{Binding QuestionId}"/>
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </Expander.IsExpanded>
                <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                    <!--Custom Styling Here, All Bindings Work-->
                </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                <!--Content Here, All Bindings Work-->      
            </Expander>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

**Converter (simplified)**

```
public class TestConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ControlValue", typeof(short), typeof(TestConverter), new PropertyMetadata(default(short)));

    public short ControlValue
    {
        get { return (short) GetValue(ControlValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (short)value==ControlValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? ControlValue : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

**ActiveQuestionId implementation in ViewModel - INotifyPropertyChanged is tested and works, ViewModel is DataContext on Parent UserControl**

```
    private short activeQuestionId;
    public short ActiveQuestionId
    {
        get
        {
            return activeQuestionId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != activeQuestionId)
            {
                activeQuestionId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the current DataContext value isn't inherited down to the TestConverter instance. You may perhaps better solve this by a MultiBinding with an IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: @Clemens perhaps not, is that because it is within a binding? If i bind to any other element the DataContext works fine, i.e. binding to the QuestionId property on the QuestionAssignment class.

I did try MultiBinding, but realized that it does not really support ConvertBack in a way that supports my use case. I.e. I need to set (ConvertBack) the ActiveQuestionId on the view model if IsExpanded is set to true, or do nothing if its set to false. Otherwise other sections are not notified about the change. I could of course achieve this if I disregard MVVM, but like to keep things decoupled.

Comment: If you want your converter to participate in the inheritance context, try declaring it as a resource in your `Expander`.  You also need to make it extend `Freezable` instead of `DependencyObject`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel thanks for your input, I did try to use the resource in template approach with x:Shared="False", which according to my current understanding should create a separate instance of the converter per item. I haven't used Freezable, will look into that class, but have chosen to go with a ListBox for now as it suits my need out of the box and is a more elegant solution in my case.

Comment: @SuppaiKamo Sounds good.  FYI, `Freezable` is the uppermost class that participates in the inheritance context, so if you want to use an object as a binding target, it must derive from that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current DataContext value is not inherited down to the TestConverter instance.

You may avoid this complex binding altogether and implement your control by using a ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionSection.QuestionAssignments}"
         SelectedValuePath="QuestionId"
         SelectedValue="{Binding ActiveQuestionId}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsSelected,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            ...
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Works beautifully and definitely seems to be the appropriate approach for my use case, thanks. I need to know the capabilities of my controls better it seems :)